# Is it possible for the resultant of four non-coplanar vectors to be zero?

Tags: vectors, geometry

If yes, can you describe it please? with an example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take three generic $\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \vec{v_3}$ and $\vec{v_4} = -(\vec{v_1}+ \vec{v_2}+ \vec{v_3})$.